# How to migrate an app from a prod server into a sandbox with Force.com IDE

Tags: force.com, deployment, ide, migration

I need to to do the following:

1. Pull code for components from prod env into Eclipse
2. Remove items that are not needed for deployment
3. Deploy components to sandbox

Right now this is what I've been doing:

1. Create a new Force.com Project and point it towards the prod env
2. Pull down all components available into project
3. Create a new Force.com Project and point it towards sandbox
4. Pull down all components available from sandbox
5. Copy and paste each desired component from first project and paste into appropriate folder in sandbox project
6. Right-click on src folder in sandbox project and click on "Deploy to server"
7. Point the deployment towards sandbox server
8. Validate

After validation I am given the error below.  Also, when I log into the sandbox in the web browser and look at the deployment monitoring info the attempts at deployment are not logged and there is no error information.

Thank you so much!!

[image: error displayed after validation]

Comment: With that error Id its hard to tell what error-ed it of .So add components one by one and keep validating instead of all at a shot .One thing you need to be careful will be of dependency.Also if you are familiar with ANT tool use that instead of IDE

Comment: You could use ANT to deploy it from production to sandbox. Download all the metadata you need and I think i should work.

Answer (score 3):

It’s difficult to tell exactly what’s going wrong from your description, but given you have a lot of manual steps in the process I’m not surprised that something is going wrong along the way.

As several others have mentioned, there are a number of tools you can use which minimise the number of manual steps and help you quickly and reliably manage your deployments, such as:

1. MavensMate
2. Salesforce Change Sets
3. [Gearset Deploy](http://www.gearset.com)

I’m a part of the Gearset team, so I decided to run through your workflow in the cloud version of our app to demonstrate how to quickly deploy changes from production to sandbox org. You can see the whole post on our blog here: http://gearset.com/blog/walkthrough-migrating-from-production-to-sandbox

We want to make the whole process of Salesforce deployment and moving things between orgs really simple and any feedback is always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to answer your question RE Eclipse IDE and that error. Try deploying changes one by one like Mohith Shrivastava suggested

For what you are trying to do, the best option seems to be using the Salesforce Outbound Change Set Wizard, you can use it to migrate just selected items and for a once off operation which this sounds like, that would be the simplest way (not necessarily the best though).

Just go through the wizard and tick the boxes for items you want sent

---

To be honest, I've always found the Force.com IDE always a little buggy and never quite worked the way I expected. I recommend using [Mavens Mate](http://mavensmate.com), it is use friendly and easy to perform deployments with.

1. Setup the project (via Sublime Text 3)
2. Make the changes required
3. Select MavensMate > Deploy To Server
4. Tick the files you would like to deploy and click on Deploy

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just create a sandbox from production? I'm assuming because you have code in the sandbox that you want to keep? If thats the case it maybe easier to do it the other way around. Create a sandbox and then push your code from your current sandbox into it.

Not everything is in meta data. I usually get Salesforce internal errors during deployment for functionality that hasn't been switched on that isn't in meta data. For example if you have code around the use of Knowledge or LiveAgent and that hasn't been switched on in your sandbox then you may get odd errors or even code referencing a sites page that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Unmanaged Package in the production org to group the metadata you want to pull.  To clarify, you will only use the Unmanaged Package to group metadata but will never upload the package to distribute it to other orgs.

To do this with the Force.com IDE:

1. In your production org, go to Setup -> Create -> Packages and create a package for the code you want to migrate.
2. Use the Add button to add all the metadata from the org you want to migrate.  One neat feature is that dependencies of anything you include will also be included in the package (referred to as spidering)
3. Set up a new Force IDE project against your production org.  When prompted to select metadata, use the from package option rather than selecting metadata types.  Select the package you created in step 1

When you use this method, the Force IDE will only pull the metadata you included in the package rather than all metadata.  The resulting package can be deployed into your sandbox org.  It will create an Unmanaged Package in the sandbox org and add all the metadata from the package you retrieved from production into the package in the sandbox org.

If you feel like going the ant route, you can take a look at our build scripts which are set up to handle working with Unmanaged Packages in this way: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCI

The targets that are relevant in the build script are:

- **retrievePackagedToSrc**: retrieves all metadata from the package in the target org into the src directory
- **uninstall**: deletes all metadata from the package
- **deployWithoutTest**: deploys all metadata
- **runAllTests**: runs all apex tests