# Deploy custom fields from one Org to another Org

Tags: deployment, eclipse

I only want to deploy custom fields of an object from One Org to another Org.Both Orgs are not related to each other.This Object has both managed package fields and some custom fields.I only want the custom fields to deployed.

For this I have created a project in an eclipse and added the object to it.But when I added the object to eclipse all components of object(record types,managed fields,custom fields,validation rules,search layouts) is added to eclipse.I don't see a way to select the subset of custom fields in eclipse.

FYI..I am not familiar with Ant tool(Migration Tool) so wondering any other ways to acheive this.

What is the approach I need to follow ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with the Force IDE.  The easiest for me is to use an Unmanaged Package in the the source org to group the metadata you want to retrieve.  I wrote about using this approach with the Force IDE in this post:

[How to migrate an app from a prod server into a sandbox with Force.com IDE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49242/how-to-migrate-an-app-from-a-prod-server-into-a-sandbox-with-force-com-ide/56357#56357)

Comment: When you say "Force IDE" do you mean eclipse? I can't find the path  Setup -> Create -> Packages

Comment: The Force IDE is built on top of eclipse.  If you're able to retrieve an object from Salesforce inside eclipse, you're using the Force IDE to do it.  The Setup -> Create -> Packages is not inside the Force IDE but inside your Salesforce org accessible through a browser.  Once you have the package created and the metadata you want to move added to the package, then you create a new project in eclipse and tell it to pull from the package you created in the org.

Comment: @JasonLantz What happens if that unmanaged package is of different version to Target org. For example, Source org is using Spring 2019, Target org is using Winder 2019? There is where I cannot use unmanaged package

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by a previous answer **Force.com IDE** should also be a good option.
And so is creating an **unmanaged package** in your source org, upload the package, and using the installation URL install it in your destination org. 
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=uploading_packages.htm&language=en_US

Or use the **workbench** to select and export your components. Only requirement is the need for `package.xml` to list out all the components that you require.
https://workbench.developerforce.com/

Or use **ANT** script to export your components and deploy them in your org. Here again you need the `package.xml` and also need to set it up. The below guide should get you started on that.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

When you add an object to your workspace is eclipse, you can actually select the fields that you want to be imported. See the following screenshot.

Only the selected fields will be added to your project.

[image: screenshot]